# Write multiple files atomically

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

Suppose I have a folder with a few files, images, texts, whatever, it only matters that there are multiple files and the folder is rather large (> 100 mb). Now I want to update five files in this folder, but I want to do this atomically, normally I would just create a temporary folder and write everything into it and if it succeeds, just replace the existing folder. But because I/O is expensive, I don't really want to go this way (resaving hundreds of files just to update five seems like a huge overhead). But how am I supposed to write these five files atomically? Note, I want the writing of all files to be atomic, not each file separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could adapt your original solution:

1. Create a temporary folder full of hard links to the original files.
2. Save the five new files into the temporary folder.
3. Delete the original folder and move the folder of hard links in its place.

Creating a few links should be speedy, and it avoids rewriting all the files.

Comment: Be warned: although this avoids there ever being a time when some of the new files are present and others are not, it does mean there will be a time when an outside observer will see the folder being completely missing. You can't atomically remove the old folder and move the new one into place. (By the way, step 3 should be: 3a. rename the original folder out of the way, 3b. rename the new folder into place, 3c. delete the renamed original folder. Deferring deletion of the original folder will minimize the time that outside observers can see something strange.)

Comment: I thought of another problem with this approach. What if some other process creates a file in the destination after step 1 and before step 3a? For example, consider two programs simultaneously employing this same technique. You lose files if you're not careful. A safer approach might be to: create your file in a temporary location, rename the destination folder as an ersatz means of claiming exclusive access to it, move your files in, and then rename it back. However, what you're trying to do is inherently non-atomic and you can't really get around it. You just have to pick your poison.